# Can't restart Apache2 - Error

Tags: server, apache2, ssl, restart, https

I currently have a problem with my website after trying to renew my SSL certificat.

I've done all the steps mentionned in this tutorial : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-commercial-certificate-authority

On the final part when I have to enter the line **sudo service apache2 restart** I got this error message:

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

**systemctl status apache2.service**

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-05-18 00:18:34 UTC; 6s ago
  Process: 4867 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 7254 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1045 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 18 00:18:34 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
May 18 00:18:34 apachectl[7254]: Action 'start' failed.
May 18 00:18:34 apachectl[7254]: The Apache error log may have more information.
May 18 00:18:34 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 18 00:18:34 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 18 00:18:34 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
apache2ctl configtest
Syntax OK
apachectl configtest
Syntax OK
```

I tried the **configtest** command to see if I had any synthx error, but everything seems to be ok.

**journalctl -xe**

```
May 18 15:33:52 sshd[31542]: Failed password for i
May 18 15:33:53 sudo[31549]:     root : TTY=pts/0
May 18 15:33:53 sudo[31549]: pam_unix(sudo:session
May 18 15:33:53 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HT
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit apache2.service has begun starting up.
May 18 15:33:53 apachectl[31555]: Action 'start' f
May 18 15:33:53 apachectl[31555]: The Apache error
May 18 15:33:53 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Contr
May 18 15:33:53 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Faile
May 18 15:33:53 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Ap
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit apache2.service has failed.
--
-- The result is RESULT.
May 18 15:33:53 sudo[31549]: pam_unix(sudo:session
May 18 15:33:55 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= M
lines 1128-1150/1150 (END)
May 18 15:33:52 sshd[31542]: Failed password for invalid user bdt from 206.18
May 18 15:33:53 sudo[31549]:     root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; C
May 18 15:33:53 sudo[31549]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user
May 18 15:33:53 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit apache2.service has begun starting up.
May 18 15:33:53 apachectl[31555]: Action 'start' failed.
May 18 15:33:53 apachectl[31555]: The Apache error log may have more informat
May 18 15:33:53 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exi
May 18 15:33:53 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 18 15:33:53 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit apache2.service has failed.
--
-- The result is RESULT.
May 18 15:33:53 sudo[31549]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user
May 18 15:33:55 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=fa:52:65:0e:6a:71:fe:00:
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
lines 1128-1150/1150 (END)
May 18 15:33:52  sshd[31542]: Failed password for invalid user bdt from 206.189.212.33 port 38420 ssh2
May 18 15:33:53  sudo[31549]:     root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service ap
May 18 15:33:53  sudo[31549]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by root(uid=0)
May 18 15:33:53  systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit apache2.service has begun starting up.
May 18 15:33:53  apachectl[31555]: Action 'start' failed.
May 18 15:33:53  apachectl[31555]: The Apache error log may have more information.
May 18 15:33:53  systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 18 15:33:53  systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 18 15:33:53  systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit apache2.service has failed.
--
-- The result is RESULT.
May 18 15:33:53  sudo[31549]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 18 15:33:55  kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=fa:52:65:0e:6a:71:fe:00:00:00:01:01:08:00 SRC=185.1
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
lines 1128-1150/1150 (END)
May 18 15:33:52  sshd[31542]: Failed password for invalid user bdt from 206.189.212.33 port 38420 ssh2
May 18 15:33:53  sudo[31549]:     root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service apache2 restart
May 18 15:33:53  sudo[31549]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by root(uid=0)
May 18 15:33:53  systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit apache2.service has begun starting up.
May 18 15:33:53  apachectl[31555]: Action 'start' failed.
May 18 15:33:53  apachectl[31555]: The Apache error log may have more information.
May 18 15:33:53  systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 18 15:33:53  systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 18 15:33:53  systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit apache2.service has failed.
--
-- The result is RESULT.
May 18 15:33:53  sudo[31549]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 18 15:33:55  kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=fa:52:65:0e:6a:71:fe:00:00:00:01:01:08:00 SRC=185.151.242.187 DST=167.99.179.159 LEN=40 T
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
lines 1128-1150/1150 (END)
May 18 15:33:52  sshd[31542]: Failed password for invalid user bdt from 206.189.212.33 port 38420 ssh2
May 18 15:33:53  sudo[31549]:     root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service apache2 restart
May 18 15:33:53  sudo[31549]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by root(uid=0)
May 18 15:33:53  systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit apache2.service has begun starting up.
May 18 15:33:53  apachectl[31555]: Action 'start' failed.
May 18 15:33:53  apachectl[31555]: The Apache error log may have more information.
May 18 15:33:53  systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 18 15:33:53  systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 18 15:33:53  systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit apache2.service has failed.
--
-- The result is RESULT.
May 18 15:33:53  sudo[31549]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 18 15:33:55  kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=fa:52:65:0e:6a:71:fe:00:00:00:01:01:08:00 SRC=185.151.242.187 DST=167.99.179.159 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=240 ID=15380 PROTO=TCP
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
lines 1128-1150/1150 (END)
May 18 15:33:52  sshd[31542]: Failed password for invalid user bdt from 206.189.212.33 port 38420 ssh2
May 18 15:33:53  sudo[31549]:     root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service apache2 restart
May 18 15:33:53  sudo[31549]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by root(uid=0)
May 18 15:33:53  systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit apache2.service has begun starting up.
May 18 15:33:53  apachectl[31555]: Action 'start' failed.
May 18 15:33:53  apachectl[31555]: The Apache error log may have more information.
May 18 15:33:53  systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 18 15:33:53  systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 18 15:33:53  systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit apache2.service has failed.
--
-- The result is RESULT.
May 18 15:33:53  sudo[31549]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 18 15:33:55  kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=fa:52:65:0e:6a:71:fe:00:00:00:01:01:08:00 SRC=185.151.242.187 DST=167.99.179.159 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=240 ID=15380 PROTO=TCP SPT=21789 DPT=3377 WINDOW=1024 R
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
lines 1128-1150/1150 (END)
May 18 15:33:52  sshd[31542]: Failed password for invalid user bdt from 206.189.212.33 port 38420 ssh2
May 18 15:33:53  sudo[31549]:     root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service apache2 restart
May 18 15:33:53  sudo[31549]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by root(uid=0)
May 18 15:33:53  systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit apache2.service has begun starting up.
May 18 15:33:53  apachectl[31555]: Action 'start' failed.
May 18 15:33:53  apachectl[31555]: The Apache error log may have more information.
May 18 15:33:53  systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 18 15:33:53  systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 18 15:33:53  systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit apache2.service has failed.
--
-- The result is RESULT.
May 18 15:33:53  sudo[31549]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 18 15:33:55  kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=fa:52:65:0e:6a:71:fe:00:00:00:01:01:08:00 SRC=185.151.242.187 DST=167.99.179.159 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=240 ID=15380 PROTO=TCP SPT=21789 DPT=3377 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

When I try to access the folder **/usr/sbin/apachectl** by sFTP, we can see this error message:
[Directory /usr/sbin/apache2ctl: no such file or directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trvDO.png)

In the file **/var/log/apache2/error.log**, I got :

```
[Mon May 18 15:33:53.451709 2020] [ssl:error] [pid 31566] AH02579: Init: Private key not found
[Mon May 18 15:33:53.451789 2020] [ssl:error] [pid 31566] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag
[Mon May 18 15:33:53.451800 2020] [ssl:error] [pid 31566] SSL Library Error: error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_template_noexp_d2i:nested asn1 error
[Mon May 18 15:33:53.451807 2020] [ssl:error] [pid 31566] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag
[Mon May 18 15:33:53.451815 2020] [ssl:error] [pid 31566] SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error (Type=RSAPrivateKey)
[Mon May 18 15:33:53.451823 2020] [ssl:error] [pid 31566] SSL Library Error: error:04093004:rsa routines:old_rsa_priv_decode:RSA lib
[Mon May 18 15:33:53.451830 2020] [ssl:error] [pid 31566] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag
[Mon May 18 15:33:53.451837 2020] [ssl:error] [pid 31566] SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error (Type=PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO)
[Mon May 18 15:33:53.451842 2020] [ssl:emerg] [pid 31566] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /var/log/apache2/error.log for more information
[Mon May 18 15:33:53.451846 2020] [ssl:emerg] [pid 31566] AH02564: Failed to configure encrypted (?) private key mydomain.com:443:0, check /root/certificate/mydomain.com.key
AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

Any help would be really appreciated. If you need to check something else, let me know what you need and how I can get the information.
Thank you!

Comment: Hi, please check the error log in `/var/log/apache/error.log`, this will contain the error which you'd need to solve.

Comment: Thank you very much, I added apache / error.log in my question. It can't find the key, but it still knows that the key is in the certificate folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of [MichielB](https://askubuntu.com/users/101876/michielb) I have found the cause and the solution to my problem.

As [MichielB](https://askubuntu.com/users/101876/michielb) pointed out, I had to check the **error.log** file to find the cause of my problem.

> Hi, please check the error log in **/var/log/apache/error.log**, this will contain the error which you'd need to solve. - [MichielB](https://askubuntu.com/users/101876/michielb)

So I have downloaded this file on my computer and opened it in a text editor to read the content. As we can see in the log file (see question for reference), the two important lines are :

```
[Mon May 18 15:33:53.451709 2020] [ssl:error] [pid 31566] AH02579: Init: Private key not found
```

Which indicates that the key can't be found (doesn't exist).

```
[Mon May 18 15:33:53.451846 2020] [ssl:emerg] [pid 31566] AH02564: Failed to configure encrypted (?) private key mydomain.com:443:0, check /root/certificate/mydomain.com.key
```

Which indicates where the key should be (in my case).

So I checked in the **/root/certificate/** folder to find if the **mydomain.com.key** file was missing, but it was there as expected.

The next step was to download the **mydomain.com.key** file to my computer and open it in a text editor to check the content.

It was then that I quickly understood the problem: **I did not have the right key** or even the right file.

I do not know if it was a mishandling on my part during one of the stages of the installation of my SSL certificate, but my .key file was not a key. I knew it because there were no following tags in the file:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----

        {content}

-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

So if you have a problem similar to mine, **make sure you have a .key file** that your 000-default.conf or mydomain.com.conf file points to and make sure it is **the correct key for the installed certificate** (and not a key from the previous certificate, for example).

Thank you very much [MichielB](https://askubuntu.com/users/101876/michielb) for your help! You made my day!

Answer (score 1):

`journalctl -xe` is helpful in such cases too. You have to go up with `up arrow` on keyboard to see the issue. In my case it was `SSLProxyEngine` and alike configuration problem in `sites-enabled` apache configs.